# UTL_DBWS - calling a web service from Oracle

Tags: web-services, oracle10g

Hope someone can help me. My problem is that I can’t seem to call any web services from Oracle `(Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.1.0.5.0.)`

The web service I was originally working on can be invoked from a browser interface, but when invoked from Oracle I get the following error message:

```
Fel pσ rad 1:
ORA-29532: Java-anrop avslutades av ouppfσngat Java-undantag:
java.rmi.RemoteException: java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is:
dynamic invocation error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Error parsing envelope
ORA-06512: vid “SYS.UTL_DBWS”, rad 404
ORA-06512: vid “SYS.UTL_DBWS”, rad 401
ORA-06512: vid “PRODPACK.HELLOWORLD”, rad 163
```

The first couple of lines are in Swedish, and are telling me politely that my code has caused an uncaught java exception.

I have tried to google this but have not been able to find anything that can help me.

I tried to call an example web service that I found in this article:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/utl_dbws10g.php

But I get the same error.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with utl_dbws and it turned out that we had a 'partial' install of java on our 10g instance.  Our dba had to finish the installation and then everything worked.

However, even after that I switched to using [UTL_HTTP](http://martin-mares.com/2010/08/oracle-db-consume-wsdl-webservice-in-plsql/) ([and another link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ConsumingWebServices9i.php))and found it easier (esp. since there seems to be more documentation around it and I had to go through a proxy)

Comment: Thanks Harrison!
That just might confirm a gnawing suspicion that I have had that there might be some miss-match between oracle and the java classes. I will have to check if its ok to reinstall them. In the mean time I will test the UTL_HTTP link and see if it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @PaulBrennan No problem.  I actually found UTL_HTTP to be quite easy to work with, granted playing around with the resulting SOAP class got me to understanding the underlying protocols that much better.

Comment: This is just an update to show the final(?) outcome/solution to this problem. I abandoned my attempt to use UTL_DBWS and followed Harrison's advice to try out the SOAP_API/UTL_HTTP way of calling the web service. Initially this did not work due to two problems. 

1. My XPath expression was not entirely correct. Thanks to Allan's Online XPath Tester [link](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx)  I managed to figure out what was wrong. 

2. The expath expression contained a namespace, which just seemed to cause errors. I bypassed this by using the "local-name" xpath function.

Comment: @PaulBrennan, glad that you got the utl_http to work.  I had quite a bit of xPath issues as well in getting it started up (and had to learn how to handle wallet etc) but it is working like a champ now that I have it down.

Comment: How to complete the installation of java on an 10g instance? Is it possible to see what the possible problem is without installation (we have the same error)"

Comment: @Friek, our oracle dba took care of the finishing off the java installation.  if memory serves me correctly, they had done an upgrade and missed the steps on installing the changes to java.  I believe he found all the info he needed in oralink.