# error when invoking web services using UTL_DBWS

Tags: web-services, oracle, plsql

I followed the example in [Oracle tutorial](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/utl_dbws10g.php) how to invoke the web service.

When I run it with

`l_wsdl_url        := 'http://www.oracle-base.com/webservices/server.php?wsdl';`

It works fine.

However, if I create my own dynamic web application in Eclipse, and generate the SAME wsdl that oracle [presents](http://www.oracle-base.com/webservices/server.php?wsdl), and change the code to be:

```
l_wsdl_url        := 'http://localhost:8080/MyProject/services/CalculatorPort?wsdl';
```

I get an exception:

```
    ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: 
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: error.build.wsdl.model: oracle.j2
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: 
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: error.build.wsdl.model: oracle.j2
```

So I added to the code:

```
sys.utl_dbws.set_http_proxy('http://localhost:8080');
```

I get the following exception:

```
 ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: 
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: error.build.wsdl.model: oracle.j2ORA-29532: Java call 
terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: 
    error.build.wsdl.model: oracle.j2ee.ws.commons.tools.api.WsdlValidationExcpetion:
 faultCode = PARSER_EXCEPTION error reading file at: 
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/services/CalculatorPort?wsdl: http://localhost
```

The web services runs just fine out of PL/SQL (with soap-ui) tool.

The PL/SQL is sitting behind firewall on a different machine than my localhost application.

What's wrong in the request?

Comment: I've had issues with utl_dbws (mainly due to upstream issues such as it not being installed properly).  Try using utl_http to see if you can get that to work (just the out going bit as a [test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493433/utl-dbws-calling-a-web-service-from-oracle/6510287#6510287) ).  Also what version of Oracle are you on?

Comment: oracle 10g. I will try url_http what is the difference?

Comment: [UTL_HTTP](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/search?remark=quick_search&word=UTL_HTTP&tab_id=&format=ranked) is more low level than utl_dbws (it can call html pages as well as web services etc).  on that note, however, it requires more work to interrogate the resulting SOAP call.  I have found the 'low-level' utl_http to be easier to work with  -- probably due to the abundance of examples out there!  But it should be able to show you if you can even make the connection....

Comment: is the oracle instance you are testing on local to your computer?  (the 'localhost' will only work if you are running oracle locally (the pl/sql engine is running on the oracle instance, so if it is out on server 123 then you'll need to quantify the WSDL service within your package with an address visible to the Oracle Box.  The 'set_http_proxy' is to tell the dbws to utilize a proxy server, not just point to your box.

Comment: Just to be clear, Oracle-Base *not* an official Oracle site.  It is a web-site maintained by Tim Hall (who is a really clever chap and knows his onions).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what is wrong is  the fact that you are trying to call localhost in a different machine than yours. When testing on PL/SQL, please replace localhost by the ip of the machine where the web service is.