# Calling .net WS (OPERATION_STYLE=document) from oracle(PL/sql) using UTL_DBWS package

Tags: asp.net, web-services, oracle, plsql

I have created a web service using ASP.NET.
I tried to access this url from a PL/sql program through UTL_DBWS package. After execution i am receiving below error:

ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: port: {http://tempuri.org/}Service1Soap 
does not contain operation: Envelope

Can any one of you please tell what steps of configuration I am missing.

I really apprcite your help.

Oracle procedure to call to asp.net service is :

```
create or replace procedure check_dbws

AS

    l_service          UTL_DBWS.service;
    l_call             UTL_DBWS.call;

    l_wsdl_url         VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_namespace        VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_service_qname    UTL_DBWS.qname;
    l_port_qname       UTL_DBWS.qname;
    l_operation_qname  UTL_DBWS.qname;

    l_xmltype_in       SYS.XMLTYPE;
    l_xmltype_out      SYS.XMLTYPE;
    p_fault_node         xmltype;
    l_return           NUMBER;
    l_int_type  utl_dbws.qname;
    l_string_type utl_dbws.QNAME;
BEGIN

    l_wsdl_url := 'http://localhost/TestWebService/Service1.asmx?wsdl';
    l_namespace := 'http://tempuri.org/';

    l_service_qname := UTL_DBWS.to_qname(l_namespace, 'Service1');
    l_port_qname := UTL_DBWS.to_qname(l_namespace, 'Service1Soap');
    l_operation_qname := UTL_DBWS.to_qname(l_namespace, 'DBConnect');

    l_service := UTL_DBWS.create_service (
    wsdl_document_location => URIFACTORY.getURI(l_wsdl_url),
    service_name => l_service_qname);

    l_call := UTL_DBWS.create_call (
    service_handle => l_service,
    port_name => l_port_qname,
    operation_name => l_operation_qname);
    utl_dbws.set_property (l_call,'SOAPACTION_USE','TRUE');
    utl_dbws.set_property (l_call,'SOAPACTION_URI', 'DBConnect');

    utl_dbws.set_property(l_call,'ENCODINGSTYLE_URI', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/');
    utl_dbws.set_property(l_call,'OPERATION_STYLE', 'document'); 

    l_string_type :=utl_dbws.to_qname('http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema','String'); 
    utl_dbws.add_parameter(l_call,'Request',l_string_type,'ParameterMode.IN');
    utl_dbws.set_return_type(l_call,l_string_type);
    l_xmltype_in:=sys.xmltype('<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v002="http://tempuri.org/DBConnect">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <DBConnect>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <DBConnect>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>');


    l_xmltype_out := UTL_DBWS.invoke (call_handle => l_call,,request => l_xmltype_in);
    p_fault_node := l_xmltype_out.extract('//soap:Fault', 'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
    if (p_fault_node is not null) then
        dbms_output.put_line(p_fault_node.getclobval());

        l_return:=2;
    elsif l_xmltype_out is not null then
        dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype_out.getclobval());
        l_return:=1;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('errorin fault'||sqlerrm);
        l_return:=0;
    end if;

    UTL_DBWS.release_call (call_handle => l_call);
    UTL_DBWS.release_service (service_handle => l_service);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_result.AccessVarchar2);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493433/utl-dbws-calling-a-web-service-from-oracle/6510287#6510287) here; you may not have all the Java classes required to get UTL_DBWS to work.  And, per my answer there, I'll reiterate, I found it much easier to use UTL_HTTP than UTL_DBWS and continue to use UTL_HTTP since I ran into so many limitations and issues with UTL_DBWS.

Comment: Thanks for quick response...I have alreday implemented the same functionality by using UTL_http, but there is requirment to implement the same one by using UTL_DBWS 
Becuse I have open oracle sessions issue in case calling ws didn't responde back or down.  I have a sample program that call an oracle ws succesfully by using utl_dbws with same code.