# UTL_DBWS - SOAPException: Error parsing envelope

Tags: web-services, oracle, parsing, soap, envelope

I hope someone can help me. My problem is that I can’t seem to call any web services from Oracle (Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0.)

The web service I am working on can be invoked from a browser interface, but when invoked from Oracle I get the following error message:

> 11:12:10  ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.rmi.RemoteException: java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is:
>
> 11:12:10      dynamic invocation error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Error parsing envelope
>
> 11:12:10  ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_DBWS", line 404
>
> 11:12:10  ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_DBWS", line 401
>
> 11:12:10  ORA-06512: at "SYS.ADD_NUMBERS", line 39

So I found an example that used a public available webservice. But I still get the same error.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/consuming-web-services-9i.php

I found an other stackoverflow topic with this error. But the solution is to complete the java install. But I can't find any more information on what to do or how to know when there is a problem with the installation.

[UTL_DBWS - calling a web service from Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493433/utl-dbws-calling-a-web-service-from-oracle)

Any idea's how to fix this?